# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

Using Pointcut for Spring AOP is not working otherwise it works well.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Without Pointcut working code :

```
@Before("execution(public * spring.beans.Triangle.set*(*))")    
public void beforeonlySetTriangle_FirstAspect()
{
    System.out.println("beforeonlySetTriangle_FirstAspect only for Triangle is called");
}
@Before("execution(public * spring.beans.Triangle.set*(*))")    
public void beforeonlySetTriangle_SecondAspect()
{
    System.out.println("beforeonlySetTriangle_SecondAspect only for Triangle is called");
}
```

With Pointcut  code  gives error:

```
@Before("setTrianglePointCutter()") 
public void beforeonlySetTriangle_FirstAspect()
{
    System.out.println("beforeonlySetTriangle_FirstAspect only for Triangle is called");
}
@Before("setTrianglePointCutter()") 
public void beforeonlySetTriangle_SecondAspect()
{
    System.out.println("beforeonlySetTriangle_SecondAspect only for Triangle is called");
}

@Pointcut("execution(public * spring.beans.Triangle.set*(*))")
public void setTrianglePointCutter()
{

}
```

Exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut setTrianglePointCutter
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:209)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:263)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:295)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 11 more
```

spring.xml config file :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean id="triangle" class="spring.beans.Triangle">
<property name="name" value="TriangleName"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="circle" class="spring.beans.Circle">
<property name="name" value="CircleName"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="shapeService" class="spring.service.ShapeService" autowire="byName"/>
<bean id="loggingAspect" class="spring.aspect.LoggingAspect" />


</beans>
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your exception. It works fine for me. Is there anything you aren't showing us?

Comment: @Reimeus deleted their answer/comment. Your problem is with wrong versions of `aspectj`.  Go up to 1.7.2

Comment: You must have made this as answer ! anyway thank you.I solved because of your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/581630/Spring/Pointcut-methods) that error occurs with old version of runtime AspectJ jars. Upgrade to the latest versions for the `aspectjrt`, i.e. `1.7.3`

Comment: Thanks for reply but even after changing as you replied getting the exception.

Comment: The error seems to point to a config issue. Can you post the relevant parts of your application context?

Comment: please check updated the Question with xml am using.

Comment: TBH, not sure but could be a JAR version issue, check out [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/581630/Spring/Pointcut-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes because of conflicting version of aspectj jars cause that issue which for me was the case. I just removed aspectjtools dependency, updated aspectjrt,aspectjweaver to latest versions and it solved my problem